# Can a macro call a preprocessor command?

Tags: c, macros

Can a macro call a **preprocessor** command?

For example, can I write something like,

```
#define PreProcessor(x, y)  #define x ((y)+1)
```

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: It is not possible to write on the same line the # directive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Macro-producing macros in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860273/macro-producing-macros-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to expand a macro into something that is also a preprocessor directive, as in **§6.10.3.4, 3**:

> The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence
>   is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one...

But, it is possible to conditionally define macro itself:

```
#if CONDITION_A_IS_MET
#define x ((y)+1)
#else
#define x /*...some other definition*/
#endif
```

Or use an [X-macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro):

```
#define PreProcessor(x) X(x, ((x) + 1))

/*...later*/

#define X(a, b) printf("%d, %d", a, b)
PreProcessor(5) /* Outputs 5, 6 */
```

To cover most of the common cases for that feature.