# error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to write a macro that generates code for an object pool for any given class of objects in C.
I keep getting `error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter` whenever I run the preprocessor

I've tried replacing x##y with:

```
#define CONCAT1(x, y) x##y
#define CONCAT2(x, y) CONCAT1(x, y)
```

as this was suggested in a similar question

```
#define CONCAT1(x, y) x##y
#define CONCAT2(x, y) CONCAT1(x, y)

#define DECLARE_POOL(CLASS, LEVEL1, LEVEL2) {\
\
    #define CONCAT2(CLASS, _Pool_Level1) LEVEL1\
    #define CONCAT2(CLASS, _Pool_Level2) LEVEL2\
\
    CLASS* CONCAT2(CLASS, _Pool)[LEVEL1] = { 0 };\
\
    int CONCAT2(CLASS, _Available_Head) = -1;\
    int CONCAT2(CLASS, _Available_Tail) = -1;\
\
    int CONCAT2(CLASS, _In_Use_Head) = -1;\
    int CONCAT2(CLASS, _In_Use_Tail) = -1;\
\
    int CONCAT2(CLASS, _Increase_Pool)(int Level1_Address){\
\
    }\
\
    int CLASS(int Address) {\
\
    }\
\
    int CONCAT2(CLASS, _Delete)(int Address) {\
\
    }\
\
    int CONCAT2(CLASS, s)(int Address)\
\
    }\
\
    int CONCAT2(CLASS, _Save_All)(void)\
\
    }\
\
    int CONCAT2(CLASS, _Restore_All)(void)\
\
    }\
    int CONCAT2(CLASS, _Free_All)(void)\
\
    }\
}
```

Expected: Code goes through the preprocessor and gives function prototypes for objects of type "CLASS"
Actual Results:

> error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
>    #define DECLARE_POOL(CLASS, LEVEL1, LEVEL2) {\

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Macro-producing macros in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860273/macro-producing-macros-in-c)

Comment: have your tried outputting the code after the preprocessing. perhaps via the '-E' option in `gcc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `#define` inside a macro. Or any other preprocessor directive, for that matter.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. What do you suggest?

Comment: @bostonbrooks: i guess you'll need to expand it all out. I'm not sure what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Its ok, I will try moving the #define-s outside the #define block.

Comment: @BostonBrooks I'd advise to place all code generation completely outside your C source. Make a separate program for that. Because these kind of icky macros have  about 99% chance of backfiring.